# How to retrieve array map data and store in array in android studio from firestore?

Tags: java, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

i want to retrieve array map from firestore and store it at a array, but it seems like not working at all, any ideas on how to solve it? Thanks...

---

[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xEbY.png)

---

[Firebase database example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn7yo.png)

---

[Full database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUhXH.png)

---

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXCLs.png)

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("user").document("65pH8UOnV4Pz8oxogsqsL9eE91L2");
            docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        if (document.exists()) {
                             String[] array = (String[]) document.getData().get("card");
                                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: "+ document.getData().get("card"));
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing the result , you can make model java class which have same structure as on the firestore and then use it to parse in your onComplete method.

```
//UserResponse.java


 public class UserResponse {

private ArrayList<Card> card;

public ArrayList<Card> getCard() {
    return card;
}

public void setCard(ArrayList<Card> card) {
    this.card = card;
}

public String getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(String balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhonenumber() {
    return phonenumber;
}

public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
}

private String balance;
private String email;
private String name;
private String phonenumber;


}
//Card.java
public class Card{

    private String cvv;

    private String exp;

    public String getCvv() {
        return cvv;
    }

    public void setCvv(String cvv) {
        this.cvv = cvv;
    }

    public String getExp() {
        return exp;
    }

    public void setExp(String exp) {
        this.exp = exp;
    }

    public String getCarddetail() {
        return carddetail;
    }

    public void setCarddetail(String carddetail) {
        this.carddetail = carddetail;
    }

    private String carddetail;
   
}
```

And then for in firestore get code change add the following line

```
UserResponse userResponse = document.toObject(UserResponse.class)
ArrayList<Card> cards = userResponse.getCard();
```

like this:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("user").document("65pH8UOnV4Pz8oxogsqsL9eE91L2");
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                UserResponse userResponse = document.toObject(UserResponse.class);
             ArrayList<Card> cards = userResponse.getCard();

                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: "+ userResponse.getCard());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It show DocumentSnapshot data:null because not setter/field for balance found on class

Comment: Can you share the exact error that your getting from the log? Also, do you have any balance field in your map or in the card document.Share the full document structure you are trying to parse.

Comment: yeah please refer to my post again.. i had edited and uploaded new full document structure

Comment: I have updated the answer. You just have add all the field that you are trying to parse in correct class and it will works

Comment: Not working T.T, so sorry for that, i have uploaded the error please refer to the post again. i'm so sorry for that

Comment: left the card error. it said no setter/field for card

Comment: maybe it can't access the array list in the user response, any ideas on it? sir..

Comment: Updated the UserResponse class.Can you try again?

Comment: omg it's seems working right now, can i ask last one little question? can it possible to show in list view way in android studio?

Comment: Thank you so much! I made it! I have learnt a lot from it, appreciated your kindness! hopefully you have a good days sir!